# Visual Studio 2019 Win Forms issue erratic displacement of control sizes after docking

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

When I'm docking one control into another like a 'groupBox' into a 'panel' for example, after applying the docking all the controls erratically dislocate their positions and their sizes also arbitrarily change size. Once I grab a resize handle and resize them they snap to how they're supposed too. I've been just dealing with it but it's getting really annoying and I was hoping someone might know what's going on so I can fix the issue.

Comment: Could you provide any code that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: it's not a matter of code in this instance. I could start a new C# Winform project and drag any item into the form like a groupbox for example. In the form designer properties pane, if I select dock right for example. the groupbox arbitrarily will jump to some erratic position and grow in size. so if I hold my mouse over a resize handlebar and adjust the size it will snap to the way I want it too. it's really strange behavior.